# How do I round to the nearest .05?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble figuring out how to round to the nearest .05.

For example, 12.86 would round to 12.85.

22.88 would round to 22.90.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm clearly not on the right track:

```
const roundtoNickel = (price) => {
    price = price * 10;
    price = Math.round(price);
    return price/10;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by 20, round the number, then divide by 20

```
 (Math.round(number*20)/20).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need.

```
numberA = 0.69
numberB = 0.76
numberC = 3.76

rounded = (Math.round(numberB * 10 * 2) / 2) / 10
```

`(Math.round(rating * 2) / 2)` is for .5 rounding. Basically doubling the input and then dividing by two can give you 5 -> 2.5

What I did is to add a decimal point by multiplying with 10 so it happens on another decimal point and then dividing by 10 to get the decimal point back.

Like the other answer has pointed out, that would make `(Math.round(number*20)/20).toFixed(2)` in short.